# code igniter routing

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I am trying to work out the [code igniter routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

I have a url that will look like

http://example.com/register

I want that to hit

http://example.com/account/register/normal

I also have

http://example.com/invite/something_random_here

which I want to hit

http://example.com/account/register/invite/something_random_here

I also have

http://example.com/register/something_random_here

which I want to hit

http://example.com/account/register/subscribed/something_random_here

How do I setup these routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much [Straight out of the User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

```
$route['register'] = "account/register/normal";
$route['invite/(:any)'] = "account/register/invite/$1";
```

Basically anything after `invite/` will get tacked onto the end of `account/register/invite`. I believe it only works for one segment, if you want multiple segment support you'll have to use a regular expression:

```
$route['invite/(.+)'] = "account/register/invite/$1";
```

Another usefull one (because I believe `(:any)` only works for characters) would be:

```
$route['invite/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = "account/register/invite/$1";
```

This will let all alpha-numeric values (single segment) with _ or - go through, great for GUIDs :)

Comment: Although the test of your post is correct, (:any) actually works fine for guids (that's actually what something_random_here is).

Comment: I couldn't remember the specifics, the user guide specified 'any character' so i made a safe assumption and gave you an alternative that demonstrated regex :) Glad (:any) worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe for your first URL, you would use the following route:

```
$route['register'] = "account/register/normal";
```

Your second URL, would make use of the following route:

```
$route['invite/(:any)'] = "account/register/invite/$1";
```

Both of these routes would need to be placed in your "config/routes.php" file.

Hope this helps?

Comment: Looks like @Aren beat me to the punch

Comment: Cheers for the help :D

Would accept, but as you said, Aren beat you to it!