# CodeIgniter causes server to drop connection when redirecting to routed URLs

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, routes

I have a CodeIgniter site which works fine locally, but now I've uploaded it to another server it breaks under a very specific condition.

The server will drop the connection if I try and redirect to a URL that has a route in routes.php

I.e.

```
$route['controller/dothis(:any)?'] = "controller/method/dothis$1";
$route['controller/dothat(:any)?'] = "controller/method/dothat$1";
```

The server is running Apache, and there is no error in any of the logs, the server just drops the connection, and returns nothing to the client.

The sequence of events is this:

1. Pages loads fine
2. user submits a form via POST
3. The controller receives the POST request
4. The controller calls redirect() to /controller/dothis/xxx
5. The server drops the connection

I'm stumped on this one, and have never seen this behaviour before.

**Update:**

The logs end like this:

Access log

```
2.217.174.75 - - [13/Oct/2011:18:29:04 +0100] "GET /home/index/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7209
2.217.174.75 - - [13/Oct/2011:18:31:18 +0100] "POST /home/index/ HTTP/1.1" 302 68
```

Rewrite log

```
2.217.174.75 - - [13/Oct/2011:18:31:18 +0100] [89.234.23.46/sid#2b5effefb0f0][rid#2b5ef2745340/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/staging/html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
2.217.174.75 - - [13/Oct/2011:18:31:18 +0100] [89.234.23.46/sid#2b5effefb0f0][rid#2b5ef2745340/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/staging/html/] pass through /var/www/staging/html/index.php
```

No entries in the PHP or Apache error logs.

As you can see, the form is submitted, a redirect is attempted (status 302) then the connection just goes away on the browser end.

There are no entries in syslog of Apache crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was totally unrelated to CodeIgniter.

I was storing too much data in the session (using native PHP sessions), and Apache was chucking the response away.

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a white page of death? Or browser cannot connect thingy? Firebug got any info? Specifically the network pane? Sure there isn't an error on the re-directed-to page? Tried having just some text on it?

Is your .htaccess set up correctly? Are there restrictions on apache modules on the host?

[code igniter routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723945/code-igniter-routing)

---

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's not the white page of death. 

The connection just gets dropped. There is no additional debug info, I don't even get a status value back, the connection just goes away. There is no info in the Apache logs either.

The exact same code works fine on my local server, so I'm pretty sure it's a server configuration issue, but I've no idea what it could be.

I've asked the hosting company to enable PHP error logging so I can check there.

Comment: "Are there restrictions on apache modules on the host?" What do you mean by this exactly? Also, the htaccess file is fine.

Comment: Re apache modules: mod_rewrite is used by .htaccess. What happens when the connection is dropped? What does the browser do? There shouldn't be ZERO feedback; a not found or 500 error, or DNS error, or something should be shown. Do you use firebug? If so, under the network tab, it should show the request to the routed page (GET or POST); show the headers, and response. Try getting rid of all code on all pages and just echo out some text on the pages to eliminate variables.

Comment: There is ZERO feedback, that's the main point of the problem, I don't get a response from the server, no status code, no headers, no content, the connection is dropped before the page is loaded.

Comment: Damn that sucks. Do you have CI debug on? And your logs set in config? If not, try turning on `$config['log_threshold'] = 4;` in `config.php` and make sure `$config['log_path'] = '/site/logs/';` is correct and writable. See if anything shows up there.

Comment: Yeah, they're on :-) They show the code get right down to the redirect (which is actually sent if you look at the Apache logs), then everything stops. The weird thing is, I can load the page fine if I put the URL in the browser, but I can't redirect to it.

Comment: It might be mod_rewrite. Can we see your .htaccess? Also, I added an example of a more robust .htaccess I found on the CI forum. Also, is there a live version of the site we can poke at (scrubbed/dummy content or otherwise)? I looked at the site the IP points to in the log you posted (might want to scrub that) and it's showing a routing error `Message: Undefined variable: segements`. If you were messing with router.php, make sure that that variable is spelled correctly (`segments`).